# How to exit gracefully from inside of a spawned thread in rust?

Tags: multithreading, rust, channel, rust-cargo

Currently I have the following code:

```
struct FileConfig {
    base_dir: PathBuf
}

pub fn my_func(&self, dest_addr: &'static str) {
    let (base_tx, base_rx) = mpsc::channel();
    base_tx.send(&self.fs_config.clone().base_dir);

    thread::spawn(move || {
        let tcp_stream = TcpStream::connect(dest_addr).unwrap();
        let datafile_path = if let Ok(base_dir_path) = base_rx.recv() {
            base_dir_path.join(data_file_format(trunk_id.clone()))
        } else {
            // TODO: Exit from thread gracefully 
        };

        ... // more code here
    }
}
```

Note:
`self.fs_config` is a `FileConfig` and I clone it to avoid lifetime problem

Now I have a problem, I want to Exit from a spawn thread gracefully in case there is unprecedented error.. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried just returning from the closure?

Comment: Nothing? Just `return;`?

Comment: oh yes it actually works if I would like to exit from the if let closure. But if I would like to exit from the thread immediately, what should I do?

Comment: The "if let closure" ? `return` exits from the closure you give the thread. There's no inner closure, `if let` doesn't create a closure.

Comment: hmm I tried this, lets say:
`let datafile_path = if let Ok(base_dir_path) = base_rx.recv() { return; } else { PathBuf::from("anything") }`

But it didn't exit from the thread directly and continue to compile the next line of code inside the thread

Comment: @Sacchirro that’s the inverse logic to what’s shown in the question

Comment: sorry, probably I am confusing but thanks all, I think I get it now.. comments upvoted

Comment: @Sacchirro You can probably delete this question if it's clear for you